# Connect to SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc. I am facing the following 
problem:
My username is: DESKTOP-B3DDLU2\maria

> Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-B3DDLU2\\maria'

Any idea how to overcome the `\\` instead of `\` problem? I using the following code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
r'SERVER=DESKTOP-B3DDLU2\SQLEXPRESS;'
r'DATABASE=[xxx];'
r'UID=DESKTOP-B3DDLU2'+('\\')+r'maria;'
r'PWD=xxxxx')
```

Comment: This isn't a solution to your particular problem, but a work-around: I always create dedicated SQL Server username and passwords for connecting from `pyodbc`. If you have the access level to do those, this is considered a better practice from a security standpoint as well (using a dedicated account for the service).

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the same machine on which SQL Server is running? (It appears so, given that `SERVER` and `UID` both start with `DESKTOP-B3DDLU2`.) If so, are you logged into Windows as `DESKTOP-B3DDLU2\maria` when you are running the Python code?

Comment: @FlipperPA re: *"I always create dedicated SQL Server username and passwords for connecting from pyodbc"* - Do you mean SQL Authentication username/password credentials? If so, do you create one for each potential user of the Python app? Also, the account that runs the `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` service is something else entirely, no?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, I create individual SQL Auth usernames and passwords by service. I have a dedicated user for scheduled tasks, another for each web site, ones for each vendor doing data loads, etc. I'm not familiar with SQL Express, and we don't typically have users connecting outside of a service.

Comment: @FlipperPA - Ah, okay, so when you say "a dedicated account for the service" you're referring to some other service that *connects to* the SQL Server instance, not the service *running* the SQL Server instance. Right?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, that's what I was referring to. Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\\` in a raw string when you only want a single `\`.  e.g.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
r'SERVER=DESKTOP-B3DDLU2\SQLEXPRESS;'
r'DATABASE=[xxx];'
r'UID=DESKTOP-B3DDLU2\maria;'
r'PWD=xxxxx')
```

Comment: Hi CCO thank you for your help. I tried that route because if I just use single \ ,ie. copy/paste my user, I still get the same error with the duplicated \

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Trusted_Connection=yes
```

example:

```
import pyodbc
connection_string ='DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server=<server>;Database=<DB>;Uid=<UID>;Trusted_Connection=yes'
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if you explain what this additional parameter does, and what its potential limitations are. Knowing nothing about it, I can't add anything constructive, but purely from the name, it sounds like it could be introducing some sort of security vulnerability.

Comment: Adding the `Trusted_Connection=yes` parameter overrides the entered `Uid=<UID>` and `Pwd=<PWD>` parameters and uses the current user's credentials to login. See [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/ConnectionStrings.wiki#Security) for further explanation. If the OP wants to use different credentials, this solution will not work.